# mem_fn, bind, function difference when passing parameters

Tags: c++, std-function, stdbind

As shown in the code and output below, three phenomena can be observed：

1. For mem_fn, which is `f1` in the code, whether it is passed `ff` or `&ff`, the `num_` value in the `ff` object can be modified normally after execution.
2. For bind, if `ff` is bound in advance, the `num_` value in `ff` object is not modified after execution; If you use placeholder to pass `ff` or bound `&ff` directly, it can be modified as normal.
3. For function, if the first parameter is specified as `Foo`, then `ff` is passed, and the `num_` value in the `ff` object is not modified after execution.

So my problem is that all callable objects are called just like `INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN)`. Why do the above three differences occur ?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Foo
{
    Foo(int num) : num_(num) {}
    void print_add(int i)   { num_ += i;}
     int num_;
};

int main()
{

//    cout << "check mem_fn" << endl;
    Foo ff(1);
    auto f1 = std::mem_fn(&Foo::print_add);
    f1(ff, 1);
    cout << "mem_fn pass ff, after exec, ff num : " << ff.num_ << endl;
    f1(&ff, 1);
    cout << "mem_fn pass &ff, after exec, ff num : " << ff.num_ << endl;


    auto f2 = std::bind(&Foo::print_add, placeholders::_1, placeholders::_2);
    f2(ff, 1);
    cout << "bind use placeholder_1 to pass ff, after exec, ff num : " << ff.num_ << endl;

    std::function<void(int)> f3 = std::bind(&Foo::print_add, ff, placeholders::_1);
    f3(1);
    cout << "bind pass ff, after exec, ff num : " << ff.num_ << endl;

    std::function<void(int)> f4 = std::bind(&Foo::print_add, &ff, placeholders::_1);
    f4(1);
    cout << "bind pass &ff, after exec, ff num : " << ff.num_ << endl;

    auto f5 = std::bind(f1, placeholders::_1, placeholders::_2);
    f5(ff, 1);
    cout << "bind_mem_fn pass ff, after exec, ff num : " << ff.num_ << endl;

    auto f6 = std::bind(f1, placeholders::_1, placeholders::_2);
    f6(&ff, 1);
    cout << "bind_mem_fn pass &ff, after exec, ff num : " << ff.num_ << endl;


    std::function<void(Foo, int)> f7 = &Foo::print_add;
    f7(ff, 1);
    cout << "function(Foo), pass ff, after exec, ff num : " << ff.num_ <<endl;

    std::function<void(Foo*, int)> f8 = &Foo::print_add;
    f8(&ff, 1);
    cout << "function(Foo*), pass ff*, after exec, ff num : " << ff.num_ <<endl;


}
```

The output like this:

```
mem_fn pass ff, after exec, ff num : 2
mem_fn pass &ff, after exec, ff num : 3
bind use placeholder_1 to pass ff, after exec, ff num : 4
bind pass ff, after exec, ff num : 4
bind pass &ff, after exec, ff num : 5
bind_mem_fn pass ff, after exec, ff num : 6
bind_mem_fn pass &ff, after exec, ff num : 7
function(Foo), pass ff, after exec, ff num : 7
function(Foo*), pass ff*, after exec, ff num : 8
```

Comment: what other output did you expect and why?

Comment: `f7(ff, 1);` takes its parameter by value, its a copy.

Comment: So that you have the option to choose whichever best suits  your needs.

Comment: btw it would be much easier to correlate the output with the code if it would mention the callbable that is called

Comment: I would like to know that these three are all using the way of transmitting `ff`, why the results are different. I may underestand `f7(ff,1)` just like normal parameter value passing , ff will be copied. How to explain for the other two mem_fn and bind?

Comment: what do you mean with "the other two mem_fn and bind" ? Please include also the expected output. In your output I see two cases where the member of `ff` is not incremented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you observe is the difference between making a copy of `ff` and not making a copy. In all cases, the callables call the member function and the member is modified. Only sometimes you do not see the modification on `ff` because the modification is on a copy of `ff`.

Here:

```
std::function<void(Foo, int)> f7 = &Foo::print_add;
f7(ff, 1);
// ^^ passed by value
```

a copy is made. And here

```
std::function<void(int)> f3 = std::bind(&Foo::print_add, ff, placeholders::_1);
//                                       passed by value ^^
```

as well.

---

The difference boils down to the difference between those two:

```
void make_a_copy(Foo f) {
       f.print_add(1);
}

void pass_by_ref(Foo& f) {
       f.print_add(1);
}
```

Calling those two looks the same just like `f1(ff,1)` and `f7(ff,1)` looks the same, but they do something different:

```
Foo ff;
make_a_copy(ff);   // modifies a copy of ff
pass_by_ref(ff);   // modifies ff itself
```

Comment: I may undestand `f3` and `f7`. But for `f1(ff,1)` and `f2(ff,1)`, why they can modify `ff` ?  In form they are same as `f7(ff,1)`.

Comment: @LoveAndShare you seem to expect something by mere similarity of the syntax. `operator()` of the callable returned from `mem_fn` passes the object by reference, thats why they can modify it

Comment: @LoveAndShare `f7(ff,1)` is something totally different

Comment: Thanks a lot. I may understand the examples you list. So `f1(ff,1) and f2(ff,1)` just pass the object by reference  because of the syntax ? Whether `forward` related knowledge is also involved ?

Comment: @LoveAndShare This isnt about syntax, but about how `operator()` of the type returned from `mem_fn` is defined: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn

Comment: Just like it said,
`Each argument in args is perfectly forwarded, as if by std::forward<Args>(args)....`, so `ff` would be deduced as T& (reference) by std::forward ?

Comment: @LoveAndShare the use of `std::forward` is not that crucial here. It would work exactly the same in your case if no `std::forward` would be used. The crucial point is that `ff` is passed as reference